# How is unary minus handled in "Let's build a compiler" Tutorial 11?

Tags: compiler-construction

What's the general idea around handling unary minus in tutorial 11? There doesn't seem to be a call to `Negate()`.

I'm following Crenshaw's "Let's build a compiler" course, only in C and x86. In tutorial 11 the scanner is refactored a little, and amid the refactoring the author says that they've simplified the handling of unary minus. However, my C version (which I believe to be a (fairly?) faithful transcription) doesn't seem to handle unary minus at all - it fails my tests!

I'm following from http://www.compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/tutor11.txt

Answer (score 2):

I browsed tutorial 11, and I don't see where it handles unary minus.   My recollection of that particular compiler series is that he went back and forth with the handling of unary minus, possibly because of his Pascal background.  Standard/old Pascal was somewhat different in its handling of unary minus.  For instance, see this Pascal-S grammar fragment:

```
     expression= simple_expression [ relational_operator simple_expression ] .
      relational_operator= '=' | '<>' | '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' .
      simple_expression= [ '+' | '-' ] term { addition_operator term } .
        addition_operator= '+' | '-' | OR .
        term= factor { multiplication_operator factor } .
          multiplication_operator= '*' | '/' | DIV | MOD | AND .
          factor= NUMBER | STRING | CONSTANT_NAME
              | variable_access | function_designator
              | '(' expression ')' | NOT factor .
            function_designator= FUNCTION_NAME [ actual_parameter_list ] .
```

(Grammar fragment from: http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/compilers/pascal_s_grammar/pascal_s_grammar.html)

It appears to only handle unary minus at the beginning of a simple_expression, not in factor, as many C-like languages do.

In any case, the series does add unary minus back in by the end. :-)

Finally, I ran across a link you might like:
http://code.google.com/p/letsbuildacompiler/

He develops Tiny in C.  No fair peeking until you are done with the tutorial :-)

Answer (score 0):

The idea around handling unary minus is that it is replaced with subtracting from 0, i.e. -N becomes (0 - N). The 0 is inserted by a call to Clear in the following code in procedure Expression:

```
if IsAddop(Token) then
   Clear
else
   Term;
```